# How to clear selected lines in Batch instead of the whole screen?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-console

When we use the `pause` it shows "Press any key to continue . . .". After pressing any key, the latter text remains, and the remaining text appears below it. If I use `cls` after `pause` the whole screen gets cleared.

Is there any method to remove only "Press any key to continue . . ." after pressing any key? Also, how do I clear only selected lines instead of clearing the whole screen?

Comment: Why would you not just print all the text again after the pause is continued?

Comment: I never thought of that!
But is there any way to clear only selected lines instead of clearing the whole screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multipe solutions for this problem, but batch doesn't offer a *simple* one.

The main problem of batch is, that you can't move the cursor up with normal commands.

1) You can use `cls` to clear the screen and redraw all necessary data again.

2) You can use an external program to move the cursor (this programs can be created *on the fly*), like [Move Cursor to 0,0](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5392)

3) You can abuse the `timeout` command to go back to the second line 
[Move cursor to screen home with TIMEOUT command!](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6760), a very cool trick discovered by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)

4) With Windows 10 you can use Ansi-Escape sequences to move the cursor and get many other effects, but it will work only for Win10

Comment: The first option works really well imo.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

You may also use a strange trick that combines a TAB character plus several BS ones to move the cursor up any number of lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get a BS and TAB control characters
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a"
set "TAB=   "  &  REM Be sure that TAB variable contains an Ascii 9 character

rem Leave some empty lines and do a PAUSE
echo Three empty lines below + pause
echo/
echo/
echo/
pause

rem Get width of screen buffer, set number of lines to go above
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('mode con ^| findstr "Col"') do set /A buffWid=%%a, linesAbove=3

rem Assemble the "go above" control string with the proper number of BSs
set "BSs="
set /A "cntBS = 2 + (buffWid + 7) / 8 * linesAbove"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%cntBS%) do set "BSs=!BSs!!BS!"

rem Move cursor up the desired number of lines
echo %TAB%!BSs!

echo Hello,
echo World
echo This line overwrites the one with PAUSE output
```

**IMPORTANT**: You must be sure that the line `set "TAB=    "` effectively contains a TAB (Ascii 9) character, not just spaces.

Output before the PAUSE:

```
Three empty lines below + pause



Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

... and after the PAUSE:

```
Three empty lines below + pause

Hello,
World
This line overwrites the one with PAUSE output
```

Tested on Windows 8.1

This method was discovered by DosTips user neorobin and is fully described at [this topic](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7425).

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work until I notice my programming editor is set to convert tabs into spaces. I was running notepad to place the _TAB_ anytime I needed it, until I found `for /F "tokens=2 delims=1234567890" %%# in ('shutdown /?^|findstr /bc:"E"') do set "TAB=%%#"` ... so no need _notepadding_ anymore ;-) .This was found by user *aGerman* at this [DosTips thread :new functions: :chr, :asc, :asciiMap](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1733&p=6840&hilit=capture+tab#p6853)

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in `cmd` to delete certain lines. However, I can provide a work-around:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Enable delayed expansion which is necessary to output carriage-return characters later:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Retrieve a carriage-return character:
for /F %%C in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%C"
rem // Retrieve a back-space character:
for /F %%C in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%C"
rem // Prepare message text and a string of spaces:
set "STRING=Press any key to continue . . . "
set "SPACES=                                "

rem // Use `set /P` to print message text without trailing line-break (carriage-return + line-feed):
set /P ="%STRING%" < nul
rem // Do `pause` but suppress its message text:
pause > nul
rem /* Use `set /P` to first print an invisible back-space character; this avoids a white-space
rem    character to appear first to `set /P` as it would not output such leading characters;
rem    then print a single carriage-return character to move the cursor to the beginning of the
rem    current line; then a string of spaces onto the previous message text to overwrite and so to
rem    clear it; append a single carriage-return character, so any other text is printed onto it;
rem    since there is no trailing line-break, any further text is printed at the same line: */
set /P ="%BS%!CR!%SPACES%!CR!" < nul
endlocal
```

Comment: It should be mentioned, that this code can modifiy the current line. This can be used for progress indicators

Comment: @jeb, I would not call it "modify" but "overwrite"; I mentioned it in a comment now. Anyway, I had to fix my approach as delayed expansion is needed to return a CR, and to work around the fact that `set /P` does not return leading white-spaces...